# Python automatically run program without shell staying open

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, apscheduler

I am using ApScheduler package in Python to schedule a program to run every hour. However, the shell window is never closing and if I manually close it, the program is terminated. Is there a way I can schedule a python program without seeing the window when the code is not running? Also, in .pyw the window is never being shown. So I want the window to be open during the run, and then to be closed until the next run.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open or hide the window at your leisure, you have to use a GUI package such as [TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). Then follow this tutorial on [how to show or hide a window with TkInter](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/26/tkinter-how-to-show-hide-a-window/).

If you run the script with `pythonw.exe` or you save the script as `.pyw`, the terminal window will be hidden.

You just need to open the job script using `pythonw.exe`.

Two lines in the command prompt to set all python files to open with it.
[Python Documentation - 3.3.4 Executing scripts](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/windows.html?highlight=pythonw#executing-scripts)

> 1. Launch a command prompt.
> 2. Associate the correct file group with .py scripts:
>      `assoc .py=Python.File`
> 3. Redirect all Python files to the new executable:
>      `ftype Python.File=C:\Path\to\pythonw.exe "%1" %*`

If you need to close the script but the window is hidden you can use the `psutil` module to find which executable is running your script, grab the PID, and kill it.

```
import psutil

scripts = [[" ".join(p.cmdline()), p.pid] for p in psutil.process_iter()
        if p.name().lower() in ["python.exe", "pythonw.exe"]]
```

Comment: That's great! What about when I want to terminate this schedule? Because then, if I have a schedule and can't see the shell it will be a problem to close the program right?

Comment: @aslv95 You can use the `psutil` module to search running processes and find which `python.exe` (or `pythonw.exe`) is your script.

Comment: I used it, that helps! Also I can see the running processes from Task Manager (as Python.exe). One last thing: I want the window to appear only to get input from the user. But with .pyw I don't see the window anytime. Shall I use another package to force the window to stay open until the user gives an input and close until the next scheduled time?

Comment: You could run a different visible script to get user input or you could close the hidden script, open it visibly, get user input, and then re-open it with `pythonw` or `.pyw`. At this point it's up to you.